# The render image is stretched along with the viewport camera

Tags: 3d-view, camera

This is what it looks like from the camera view. this happened when I was aplying scale  to my objects.

[image: This is what it looks like from the camera view. this happened when I was aplying scale to my objects.]

[image]

This happened when I was aplying scale to my objects.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+B to reset render border.

Comment: Ctrl Alt B didn't work

Comment: Try Alt+b then.

Comment: What is your image render size?